# PHP OOP issue with database

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I am querying usernames from database using the get() function in the DB class.. its always returning 'No users' even if there are users existing in the database..
here is my DB.php

```
<?php
class DB{
    private static $_instance = null;
    private $_pdo, 
            $_query, 
            $_error = false, 
            $_results, 
            $_count = 0;

    private function __construct(){
        try {
            $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname='. Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (!isset(self::$_instance)) {
            self::$_instance = new DB();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
        $this->_error = false;
        if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
            $x = 1;
            if (count($params)) {
                foreach ($params as $param) {
                    $this->_query->bindValue($x, $params);
                    $x++;
                }
            }

            if ($this->_query->execute()) {
                $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
            } else {
                $this->_error = true;
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function action($action, $table, $where = array()) {
        if (count($where) === 3) {
            $operators = array('=','>','<','>=','<=');

            $field    = $where[0];
            $operator = $where[1];
            $value    = $where[2];

            if (in_array($operator, $operators)) {
                $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";

                if(!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()){
                    return $this;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function get($table, $where) {
        return $this->action('SELECT *', $table, $where);
    }

    public function delete($table, $where) {
        return $this->action('DELETE', $table, $where);
    }

    public function results(){
        return $this->_results;
    }

    public function error(){
        return $this->_error;   
    }

    public function count(){
        return $this->_count;   
    }
}
```

index.php

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';

$user = DB::getInstance();
$user->get('users', array('username', '=', 'alex'));

if(!$user->count()) {
    echo 'No user';
} else {
    foreach ($user->results() as $user) {
        echo $user->username, '<br>';
    }
}
```

Am getting 'No user' even if there is existing user in the the DB if I use this..

$user = DB::getInstance()->get('users', array('username', '=', 'alex'));

but it is returning correct usernames(including 'alex') if I replace get() with query()

$user = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM users");

Comment: just show us `SELECT usernames FROM users;` output please?

Comment: @kim it returns two usernames as there are only two users in the db i.e.. Alex, Sami

Comment: if it is `Alex`, that is not equal `alex`

Answer (score 3):

In your query function when binding you do:

```
foreach ($params as $param) {
    $this->_query->bindValue($x, $params);
    $x++;
}
```

You are binding `$params` which is an array, not the value. Change `$params` to `$param` (singular) and it will likely work.

Comment: Thanks jonathan.. this fixed the error notice.. but still returning 'no user' using get() function .. :(

Answer (score 1):

Please look at this answer [Row count with PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883365/row-count-with-pdo)

> PDO has PDOStatement::rowCount(), which apparently does not work in MySql. What a pain.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing

```
$sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";
```

to

```
$sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} {$value}";
```

Comment: I tried that too.. its still returning 'No users'...! :(